# React native, undefined is not an object (evalu....)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a shopping cart in react native with redux but I'm getting an error

`undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.items.length')`

I'm following a tutorial of react redux someone suggest me to follow that tutorial to make cart,
but I'm getting that error

can someone please tell me what's going on.., below is my code

```
class Cart extends Component {
  render() {
    let addedItems = this.props.items.length ? (
      <FlatList
        data={this.props.items}
        key={(items) => items.id.toString()}
        numColumns={2}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>
            <Image style={styles.image} source={item.image} />
            <View style={styles.detailContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{item.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.subTitle} numberOfLines={1}>
                Quantity: {item.quantity}
              </Text>
              <Text style={styles.price}>Rs {item.price}</Text>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity>
              <View style={styles.buy}>
                <Text>Remove</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    ) : (
      <Text>Nothing</Text>
    );

    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>You Have Ordered:</Text>
        </View>
        <View>{addedItems}</View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    items: state.addedItems,
  };
};
```

Comment: How do you export your `Cart` component? I mean, do you connect it to Redux properly?

Comment: You are trying to access items array prop which isn't defined in your view

Comment: yup I connected it, @SamuliHakoniemi

Comment: How can I define it? can you suggest some react native tutorial or good tutorial about that? @NooruddinLakhani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
let addedItems = this.props.items && this.props.items.length ? (
```